# Why does player software fail to play movie in Acrobat Reader (Windows 7)?

Tags: video, pdf, adobe-acrobat, beamer

I have created a pdf using beamer including movies by using the instruction:

```
\movie[width=10cm,height=7cm]{Title}{videoname.avi}
```

For previous versions of Acrobat Reader, I have never had a problem with reading the videos. But now for some reason, I get an error message when I want to play the video in pdf.
I have installed the latest version of Acrobat but this did not solve the problem.
Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it is a security settings in Acrobat Reader, have you checked that ?

Comment: What does the error message state ? Have you installed Adobe Flash Player on your machine ? On Edit -> Preferences -> Multimedia Trust and Security Enhanced check the options. But I think the problem lies in Flash, check here: http://forums.adobe.com/message/4849159 .  Check also here: http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/playing-video-audio-multimedia-formats.html . You can also upload the file so we can check if it plays on our machine.

Comment: Ok if it resolves the issue please tell me and I will post it as answer to this question.